# WPF ComboBox Custom Display Selected Items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, multi-select

I followed an online tutorial to have a **multi-select** `ListBox` for a wpf project to include check boxes. I am able to manipulate the selected values accordingly on the back-end but I can't find a solution to set the displayed value on the control when **collapsed** to whatever text I want.

`XAML`

```
<ComboBox x:Name="chSel_0">
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <CheckBox x:Name="key_0" IsChecked="{Binding IsIncluded}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Channel}"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

For example if I select check box 1, 4, 6 from the available items I would like for the ComboBox to display something like 1,4,6 when **collapsed**. For now though I would be content to be able to put any text on the collapsed controller without having `IsEditable=true' on the ComboBox tag.

**UPDATE**

I've been editing the template and got this to almost "work"

`XAML`

```
<ContentPresenter DataContext="Binding" Content="{Binding KeysCfgChannels[0]}"/>
```

`C#`

```
public MainWindow()
{
    DataContext = this;
    InitializeComponent();
    CfgChannels();
}

public ObservableCollection<string> KeysCfgChannels { get; private set; }

public void CfgChannels()
{

    string val = "";
    this.KeysCfgChannels = new ObservableCollection<string> { };

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
      {
        foreach (ChSelVal ch in chCfgs[i])
        {
          if (ch.IsIncluded)
          {
            val += ch.Channel;
          }
        }
        KeysCfgChannels.Add(val);
        //val = "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16";               
    }
}
```

The issue is it will only display the new string **if** it's implicitly declared as in it will display if I do `KeysCfgChannels.Add("0 1 2 3")` but it won't work if I have it as shown.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the next link [here](http://wpf.2000things.com/?s=combobox) (#1,012 – Using a Different Data Template for the Face of a ComboBox), it should help you.

**Update**
look here for combo multiselection:
[WPF: ComboBox with CheckBoxes as items (it will even update on the fly!)](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/justguy/2009/01/19/wpf-combobox-with-checkboxes-as-items-it-will-even-update-on-the-fly/).

I'll still be glad to help if you will have the problem with the code.
Regards.

Comment: This code assumes only 1 value is selected but I have a multi-select drop down